# How do bookmakers update their odds in real-time?

Tags: references, games

I wasn't satisfied with the answers on [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110609/how-do-betting-sites-update-odds-during-a-sporting-match-in-real-time), so I'm asking again: **how do bookmakers adjust their implied probabilities as bets arrive sequentially?**

Suppose there are four things to bet on, and they're all mutually exclusive: events A, B, C and D. Suppose at this moment the bookmaker's implied probabilities are $q_a, q_b, q_c, q_d \ge 0$. A winning bet of a dollar on event $A$ pays out $(1-q_a)/q_a$. A losing bet of a dollar results in the loss of that dollar, and so on and so forth.

I understand how and when arbitrage is possible. In the case that these implied probabilities sum to something less than $1$, then one can bet in proportion to the implied probabilities to guarantee a profit in every outcome:

\begin{align}
\left\{
\left(\frac{1-q_a}{q_a}\right)q_a - q_b - q_c - q_d \right\}
& > 0 \tag{A happens}\\
\left\{
-q_a + \left(\frac{1-q_b}{q_b}\right)q_b - q_c - q_d
\right\} &> 0  \tag{B happens} \\
\left\{
-q_a - q_b + \left(\frac{1-q_c}{q_c}\right)q_c  - q_d
\right\} & > 0  \tag{C happens} \\
\left\{
-q_a - q_b - q_c + \left(\frac{1-q_d}{q_d}\right)q_d 
\right\} &> 0  \tag{D happens}
\end{align}

If the implied probabilities sum to something greater than $1$, then the same reasoning applied, but you would have to be able to bet in negative amounts. For this reason, as I understand, many bookmakers will set the implied probabilities to something greater than $1$ and hope that their clients bet in proportion to the quoted odds.

However, they obviously don't control the flow of bets. Say a large bet comes in for outcome $A$. **What is an example of a specific algorithm that would shorten the odds for outcome $A$, and then adjust the other implied probabilities so that they all continue to sum to the same number that's greater than $1$?**

If there isn't any documentation of any strategy, is there known to be a framework for thinking about this? Optimal control, perhaps? I imagine you would need some hypothesized probability distribution describing future bets, but I'm lost at how to turn that into something specific.

Finally, I'm less interested in something ad hoc. Something that's based on some framework would be nice so that one could reason about its guarantees.

Comment: The total of all bets on outcomes other than $A$ divided by the total of all bets on outcome $A$ gives a (betting) odds ratio, easily transformed to a probability.  It should be clear that the sum of all probabilities generated in this manner equals 1.  This isn't ad-hoc; it treats the relative bet sizes as wisdom-of-(betting)-crowdsourced probability estimates.

Comment: Probably needs shrinkage in the beginning, otherwise after the first bet, payout odds according to this strategy are zero and infinities. Maybe something Bayesian

Comment: Yes, and in real life, that's how it's done, based on past racing performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Python implementation based on [@jbowman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7555/jbowman)'s comment. There are two small additions, though.

1. A maximum bet size prevents the possibility of an outcome that results in the bookmaker losing more than it's willing to lose.
2. The odds that are offered take into account a [fee charged by the bookmaker.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigorish)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


class Book:

    def __init__(self, bet_info, fee, init_capital):
        self.possible_wagers = np.array(list(bet_info.keys()))
        self.init_implied_probs = np.array(list(bet_info.values()))
        self.totals = self.init_implied_probs * init_capital
        self.log_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name", "outcome", "amt", "odds"])
        self.fee = fee
        assert np.min(self.totals) > 0

    def get_odds(self):
        avail_winnings = (1-self.fee) * np.sum(self.totals) - self.totals
        return avail_winnings / self.totals

    def get_max_bet_size(self):
        return np.min(self.totals)

    def add_bet(self, name, outcome, amount):
        if outcome not in self.possible_wagers:
            print("Warning: Outcome not in possible wagers.")
            return

        if amount > self.get_max_bet_size():
            print("Warning: Not possible to place bet this large")
            return

        outcome_index = np.where(self.possible_wagers == outcome)[0][0]
        all_odds = self.get_odds()
        odds = all_odds[outcome_index]
        new_row = pd.DataFrame({"name": [name], "outcome": [outcome],
                                "amt": [amount], "odds": [odds]})
        if len(self.log_df) == 0:
            self.log_df = new_row
        else:
            self.log_df = pd.concat([self.log_df, new_row], ignore_index=True)
        self.totals[outcome_index] += amount

    def get_winners(self, winning_outcome):
        if winning_outcome not in self.possible_wagers:
            print("Warning: winning_outcome not in possible wagers.")
            return
        return self.log_df.loc[self.log_df["outcome"] == winning_outcome,]

    def write_dfs(self, winning_outcome):

        # write all bets placed
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        big_filename = f"log_df_{timestamp}.csv"
        self.log_df.to_csv(big_filename, index=False)

        # also write winners
        winners = self.get_winners(winning_outcome)
        winner_filename = f"winners_{timestamp}.csv"
        winners.to_csv(winner_filename, index=False)
```

Example use:

```
my_book = Book({"jets": .60, "steelers": .40}, .01, 100)
my_book.get_max_bet_size()
my_book.get_odds()
my_book.add_bet("Taylor", "jets", 40)
my_book.get_odds()
my_book.get_max_bet_size()
my_book.add_bet("Taylor", "jets", 40)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the code! Could you add the most important math formulas for reasoning further? A)What is the formula for the odds of an event given the amount of money bet and  B) how do the odds relate to the estimated probability of this event? :)

Comment: Trying to make it crisp in my head: Is the core idea that the estimated probability ("implied probability") of an event is the money placed on this event divided by the total money placed on bets? I guess so. Why is the odds= 1/estimated probability so much of interest?